# Migrating changes in table structure with Sinatra/Ruby/Heroku

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I have made my app with Sinatra/Ruby and deployed with Heroku. I made some extra columns to my database and manually dropped the table and put the new one up with Postgres so it works with my local version but not the Heroku one. I have already deployed my app with Heroku before this change and struggle finding a way to update the new table structure to the deployed version with terminal and heroku commands. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you try `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Yes I did but command says that there are no rake file. I haven't added one manually since I have before worked with Rails. Should I do this?